# AIC, BIC values keep changing with lag.max in VAR model

Tags: r, time-series, aic, vector-autoregression, bic

I'm using a VARselect function from `vars` package in R to select order for my model. My data set has 2 time series with 21 data points.

When I give `lag.max = 10`, the function select lag 5 model for AIC HQ FPE criteria. When I give `lag.max =15`, the function suggests lag 3 models. 
`$criteria` method shows that the AIC, FPE, HQ values keep changing for different `lag.max` with many values reaching -infinity for `lag.max = 15`.

Aren't AIC, HQ, FPE values supposed to be constant with respect to `lag.max` for smaller orders like 2?

Is this something related to degrees of freedom?

How to select a model in this scenario?

Answer (score 5):

If you have a sample of size $T$ and are exploring VAR models with up to $P$ lags, the models being compared (VAR($1$), VAR($2$), ..., VAR($P$)) are fitted on the last $T-P$ data points in the sample. When you change $P$, your estimation sample changes, so you are getting different results for the same concrete lag length $p$.

This can be seen from the `VARselect` function and anticipated from its [help file](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/vars/versions/1.5-3/topics/VARselect) which says

> **Based on the same sample size** the following information criteria and the final prediction error are computed

(the emphasis is mine).

The effect of the changing estimation sample may be particularly pronounced in small samples (small $T$) and should more or less vanish in larger samples.

How you should select a model in this situation is a tricky question. You should probably fix $P$ first, a decision that should balance the flexibility of the largest model $P$ (you want decent flexibility) vs. the shrinking size of the estimation sample $T-P$ (you want a large estimation sample). Then, for the chosen $P$, choose the model with the lowest value of the relevant information criterion.

I do not have a good explanation for why you get negative infinity in some cases. Perhaps you sample size is so small that a model with a sufficiently high lag fits the data perfectly?

Comment: Thank You Sir. I missed that logic.

Comment: Sir, Do you suggest any rule of thumb to initially choose P?

Comment: @RohitP, there are several rules in the literature and some of them are probably mentioned in some posts tagged by [tag:var], perhaps you can find them. E.g. if your data has seasonality with $s$ periods, some rules suggest you could consider $P=s$.

Comment: FYI, you can accept a satisfactory answer by clicking on the tick mark to the left. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).